# How to run WordCount example from Streaming SQL (throws NoSuchMethodError)?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run Streaming SQL(https://github.com/intel-spark/stream-sql) example wordcount. This in turn uses catalyst project. I am able to run
sbt package without any issues. However when I do spark submit of the scala code, I run into the following issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryNode$class.children(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/UnaryNode;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.WindowedPhysicalPlan.children(windowedPlans.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.WindowedPhysicalPlan.children(windowedPlans.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
```

I have included the dependancies and classfile correctly. Here is how the .sbt file looks like

```
name := "Word Count"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "spark.streamsql" %% "spark-streamsql" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: I see that following checkin is missing from stream-sql repo

https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/73348012d4ce6c9db85dfb48d51026efe5051c73

Could that be causing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a version issue, remove all spark jars and add spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar from apache spark lib folder.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? add spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0 to what? I am not sure I follow

Comment: It was a version issue. But the resolution was very specific to streaming SQL. Thanks for the suggestion though